# Angular2: Returning Promise

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, angular, promise

I am using Angular2 for my application and I have to consume Amazon S3 javascript sdk for browser.
I have the following function:

```
getBuckets() {
        var s3 = this.getS3();
        var params = {};
        s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                // What to return?
            }
            else {
                // What to return?
            }
        })
}
```

s3.listBuckets is the javascript API from Amazon for S3. It is expecting a call back function. But the caller of getBuckets is expecting a Promise. How should I change the above `getBuckets()`, such that the caller of getBuckets(), will look like:

```
getBuckets().then(
...
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With Angular 2 consider observables rather than promises

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate because the answer isn't necessarily "how to convert callbacks to promises" but is actually "upgrade the AWS SDK and you will get promises".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK for JavaScript has supported promises since version 2.3.0 released March 31st. [Here's the annoucement](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/Tx3BZ2DC4XARUGG/Support-for-Promises-in-the-SDK).

I suggest you update to the latest SDK version if you are using something earlier than 2.3.0, and then use promises instead of callbacks.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I was unaware of this. This totally solved my problem.

Comment: @UnderWood feel free to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using TypeScript you can do something like this to return a `promise`. I can imagine it would be around the same in the JavaScript style:

```
getBuckets() {
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var s3 = this.getS3();
        var params = {};
        s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, response) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(response);
            }
        })
     })
}
```

Comment: Or just update to the latest AWS SDK which supports promises.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $q, documentatie here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

That would look something like this:

```
getBuckets() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var s3 = this.getS3();
    var params = {};
    s3.listBuckets(params, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }
    })
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Oh darn I'm sorry no it isn't. I just checked the Angular2 docs and there seem to have been some major changes. I couldn't find $q in the Angular2 docs, but saw something about Observables, like @jonrsharpe mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own promise like this:

```
var myPromiseFunction = function(iserr){

 var deferred = $q.defer();

 var myreturnvalue = 'somevalue';
 if(iserr === true){

   deferred.reject('some error');

 }else{

   deferred.resolve(myreturnvalue);

 }

 return deferred.promise;

}
```

And call it like this:

```
var throwerror = false;

//or var throwerror = true; if you want to create an error
myPromiseFunction(throwerror).then(function(res){

 console.log(res);

}).catch(function(err){

 console.log(err);

})
```

This way you can create promises (they don't even have to be async but it would not have any purpose for non-async operations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But is this Angular2?

Comment: No, this is the latest 1.*. I don't know whether they changed the promises. Just try the above code in a controller or something and you'll know. (don't forget to inject $q). You can resolve callbacks like PeterH showed.